# How to pass an array from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, in Metal

Tags: metal

In GLSL, I would simply use `out vec3 array[10];`, to pass an array from the vertex shader to the fragment shader. In Metal, however, I thought to do it this way:

```
struct FragmentIn {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float3 array[10];
};
```

This produces the following error:

`Type 'FragmentIn' is not valid for attribute 'stage_in' because field 'array' has invalid type 'float3 [10]'`

How can I solve this issue? I need to do certain calculations with per-vertex data that the fragment shader will use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to "unroll" the array:

```
struct FragmentIn {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float3 thing0;
    float3 thing1;
    float3 thing2;
    float3 thing3;
    float3 thing4;
    float3 thing5;
    float3 thing6;
    float3 thing7;
    float3 thing8;
    float3 thing9;
};
```

Comment: Is there no other way?

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: I'm a graphics hobbyist and don't use Metal or C++ in my day job!

To build on the unrolling answer: since Metal Shading Language is C++, you could use macros to make working with unrolled arrays less repetitive.

### Creating repetition macros

The repetition code isn't nice, but only needs to be written once:

```cpp
#define REP1(FN, ...) FN(0, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REP2(FN, ...) REP1(FN, ##__VA_ARGS__) FN(1, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REP3(FN, ...) REP2(FN, ##__VA_ARGS__) FN(2, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REP4(FN, ...) REP3(FN, ##__VA_ARGS__) FN(3, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REP5(FN, ...) REP4(FN, ##__VA_ARGS__) FN(4, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REP6(FN, ...) REP5(FN, ##__VA_ARGS__) FN(5, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REP7(FN, ...) REP6(FN, ##__VA_ARGS__) FN(6, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REP8(FN, ...) REP7(FN, ##__VA_ARGS__) FN(7, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REP9(FN, ...) REP8(FN, ##__VA_ARGS__) FN(8, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REP10(FN, ...) REP9(FN, ##__VA_ARGS__) FN(9, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define REPEAT(N, ...) REP ## N(__VA_ARGS__)
```

### Declaring the array

A function-like macro can be used to generate the array members:

```cpp
#define DECLARE_VAR(VAR_INDEX, VAR_TYPE, VAR_PREFIX) VAR_TYPE VAR_PREFIX ## VAR_INDEX;

struct FragmentIn {
    float4 position [[position]];
    REPEAT(10, DECLARE_VAR, float3, array)
};
```

This expands to:

```cpp
struct FragmentIn {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float3 array0;
    float3 array1;
    float3 array2;
    float3 array3;
    float3 array4;
    float3 array5;
    float3 array6;
    float3 array7;
    float3 array8;
    float3 array9;
};
```

### Accessing the array

You can then either access the unrolled array elements individually, or write another function-like macro to operate on them. This example sums the unrolled array:

```cpp
#define SUM_ARRAY(VAR_INDEX, VAR_PREFIX, TOTAL) TOTAL += VAR_PREFIX ## VAR_INDEX;

float3 sumOfVectors;
REPEAT(10, SUM_ARRAY, fragmentIn.array, sumOfVectors)
```

This expands to:

```cpp
float3 sumOfVectors;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array0;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array1;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array2;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array3;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array4;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array5;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array6;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array7;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array8;
sumOfVectors += fragmentIn.array9;
```